How to use a data table in multiple steps within same scenario?

Scenario: Card Data - Matching
  Given the <card> has a value in the file
  And <count> card exist in the system 
  When the card is imported
  Then the card file <status> validation:
    | card                            | count | status |
    | card1                           | 0     | passes |
    | card2                           | 1     | passes |

I want to use data table for multiple steps instead of creating example table.
